# Error: Unable to open program file: No such file or directory (os error 2)

Tags: solana-cli, deploy, build-bpf

I am trying to deploy a `hello world` program on the blockchain through the solana cli. I tried running `cargo build-bpf` , after running the program the deploy directory is not downloaded so that I can run `solana program deploy ./target/deploy/hello_world.so` to deploy the smart contract.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this section in your Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```